# converting char to string using snprintf in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm using the below code to convert an array of characters to a string C. However the output is different from what I expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    char data[5] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'
    };
    char buff[100];
    int i = 0;

    while (data[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c Character here \n", data[i]);
        snprintf(buff, 100, "%s", & data[i]);
        printf("%s String here\n", buff);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The result I expect is

```
a Character here 
a String here
b Character here 
b String here
c Character here 
c String here
d Character here 
d String here
```

**However I'm getting this as output**

```
a Character here 
abcd String here
b Character here 
bcd String here
c Character here 
cd String here
d Character here 
d String here
```

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 7):

`data` is already a string, since it is a null-terminated sequence of characters (which is what a string is in C).

You are getting those results because you are calling `snprintf` inside a loop over `data`.

First you call `snprintf()` on `&data[0]`, which copies `data` into your buffer from `data[0]` *until it reaches the null*. Then you call `snprintf()` on `data[1]`, which copies into your buffer from `&data[1]` *until it reaches the null*. And so on...

And each time you do so, you call `printf()` on the buffer, with a `%s` parameter... which prints the argument as a sequence of characters until it reaches the terminating null (i.e. `%s` prints a string).

If you want to print a single character, use `%c`. If you want to print to the buffer character by character until you reach the null, do it manually - but `snprintf()` is designed so that you don't have to do that.

Using `snprintf()` in a more common manner:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char data[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};
  // or char data[] = "abcd";

  char buff[100] = {0};
  snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, "%s", data);
  printf("%s String here\n", buff);
  return 0;
}
```

Copy/print each character manually:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  char data[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};
  // or char data[] = "abcd";

  char buff[100] = {0}; // initialises buff by filling it with zeroes

  char *ptr = data, *buff_ptr = buff;
  while (*ptr) {
    *buff_ptr = *(ptr++);
    printf("%s current\n", buff_ptr++);
    printf("%s from the start\n", buff);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I'm in the loop for the first time, data from data[0] which is a should get copied to buff. Then immediately printing buff which should print only a right?

Comment: @AGM No. It copies from `&data[0]` through to the first null it finds, which is after `"abcd"`. The same thing is then printed.

Comment: @AGM No problem. If that answers your question, you can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)